# Ionic 3- Hide navbar and tabs on scroll down, and show on scroll up

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm working on Ionic App, I want to hide navbar and tabs on scroll down and show them on scroll up.
Anyone know how to do this? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your tried code here. No one can directly write code for you.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, I didn't try any code for this. I just need an idea for this, not the whole code.

Comment: You will get scroll direction using ionic so based on that you hide and show navbar or tab

Comment: Just subscribe to (ionScroll) on your content and e.g. compare old and new scrollTop values. if old < new you scrolled down and old > new you scrolled up.

Answer (score 0):

a very naive implementation would be:

- add a var that will be your boolean flag for state (shown/hidden)
- add change detector ref into your component (as you will need to cdr 
  change of this boolean to propagate UI)
- bind your header/footer via *ngIf directive

Something like this:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage2 {

  headerVisible: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
  }

  scrollState(event) {
    if (event.directionY == "up") {
      this.headerVisible = false;
    } else {
      this.headerVisible = true;
    }
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

And in your template:

```
<ion-header *ngIf="headerVisible">
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

But most probably instead of *ngIf you would want to alter header's/footer's height so that your overall template dealt better with margins.

Also please note that ideally you don't want scroll event to "spam" so you need to implement proper way you capture the state (up or down) without it (debounce / throttle it)